# Changing response content type in asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, internet-explorer-9, content-type

I have an asp.net Web Api controller with an Upload action. Here's the simplified version of the Upload action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Upload()
{            
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    var file = provider.Contents[0];

    try
    {
       // Save the file...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            status = "error",
            message = e.Message
        });
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        status = "success"
    });
}
```

The return type of the action has to be string, because it's used by a third-party upload widget that accepts serialized JSON only.

The problem is when I use this in IE 9, the browser doesn't accept `application/json` as a media type. So, I'll have to make sure the server returns `plain/text`. How can I do that without changing the return type of the action to `HttpResponseMessage`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Upload()
return Json(someData, "text/html");
```

Although another option to just return the json is post though an iFrame then it will not attempt to download the returning html.

Comment: As I said in the question, the Action has to return string. I can't return Json. Also, in case of IE 9, the file is uploaded through an iFrame. But, that doesn't matter.

Comment: I think you missed what it's doing. You can return a json result with a different content type. Meaning the json result can be returned as html, plain text, etc. So just don't serialize it into json if you don't want it formatted that way and specify the return type as text/plain.

Comment: Also since you are not passing anything in to your method change that to an HttpGet and you shouldn't have any issues in IE9.

Comment: I'm using asp.net Web API, not asp.net MVC. `JsonResult` is an asp.net MVC return type. But, thanks for helping me understand how the return type works. I ended up using `HttpResponseMessage` and specifying the media type as `text/html`. That way, the javascript code still returns a JSON string.